# What is the best way to implement dynamic, complex filter queries in ServiceStack OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

```
class ProductFilter{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have a product search form, result of this form is ProductFilter. In ProductFilter class, among others there is a property that stores Name of the product to be search for. What is the best way to generate a dynamic query, that add condition on product Name, only if ProductFilter.Name is not null and not empty? My first thought was to create SqlExpression object and based on condition add or not additional Where conditions to it, but SqlExpression cannot be instantiazed.

Comment: Have you considered [ServiceStack's AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query)? It allows to perform dynamic queries without the complexity of `SqlExpression` filters.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about AutoQuery it'll certainly help me, but still there are some cases (ex. Console app) in which it cannot be used, that's why I was asking about SqlExpression

Answer (score 1):

You may use generic sql code with params and check, whether query param is null like

```
select * from MyTable where (Name = @name or @name is null)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do something like this, but I can do that without ORM, not to mention paid one. I was asking how to do it in OrmLite, whether or not is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain `SqlExpressions` in OrmLite like this:

```
var exp = Db.From<ProductFilter>();

if (!productFilter.Name.IsNullOrEmpty())
    exp = exp.Where(pf => pf.Name.Contains(productFilter.Name));
```

That way you can dynamically build up the query based on whichever criteria in the filter POCO you choose.